# Weird result trying to paste/join fields from two files

Tags: bash, join, awk, paste

I'm struggling with something that I'm sure shouldn't be too tricky.
I've got several files with the following content: e.g.

file1

```
                    Model:  nfb
                    Avg(logl(X)):   -275.030
                    logl(Avg(X)):   -252.172
                    DBar:   550.060
                    Dhat:   504.343
                    pD: 45.717
                    DIC:    595.777
```

file2

```
                    Model:  b
                    Avg(logl(X)):   -273.124
                    logl(Avg(X)):   -251.069
                    DBar:   546.248
                    Dhat:   502.138
                    pD: 44.110
                    DIC:    590.358
```

Both file are tab-delimited. I'm trying to merge them so that I end up with something like this:

```
                Model:  nfb b
                Avg(logl(X)):   -275.030    -273.124
                logl(Avg(X)):   -252.172    -251.069
                DBar:   550.060 546.248
                Dhat:   504.343 502.138
                pD: 45.717  44.110
                DIC:    595.777 590.358
```

but all my merge attempts just copy information from one file directly over the other for some weird reason I can't figure out... so I'm ending up with this:

`$ paste -d $'\t' dummie1 dummie2`

```
                Model:  Model:  b
                Avg(loglAvg(logl(X)):030-273.124
                logl(Avglogl(Avg(X)):172-251.069
                DBar:   DBar:60 546.248
                Dhat:   Dhat:43 502.138
                pD: pD:717  44.110
                DIC:    DIC:777 590.358
```

and 
`$ awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1] = $2; next } { print $0, a[$1] }' dummie1 dummie2`

```
             nfbl:  b
             -275.030X)):   -273.124
             -252.172X)):   -251.069
             550.060546.248
             504.343502.138
             45.717 44.110
            DIC:    590.358 595.777
```

both sets of code work fine when I use simple files like this

```
1   a   b   c   d
1   a   b   c   d
1   a   b   c   d
1   a   b   c   d
1   a   b   c   d
```

So I'm assuming there is something fishy about the datafile that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Your files probably were created on Windows and so have control-Ms at the end of each line. Use `cat -v file` to see them and then `dos2unix` or similar to to fix them. If you edit your question to show the expected output given that sample input we can help you more.

Comment: Thanks, @EdMorton. I'm on a mac so I've used  `cat file1 | col -b >newfile1`   as an alternative to the `dos2unix` and it seems to have worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `join` as it requires the files to be sorted. After using `dos2unix` to remove the control-Ms you can do either of these:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | cut -f1,2,4
Model:  nfb     b
Avg(logl(X)):   -275.030        -273.124
logl(Avg(X)):   -252.172        -251.069
DBar:   550.060 546.248
Dhat:   504.343 502.138
pD:     45.717  44.110
DIC:    595.777 590.358

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR], $2}' file1 file2
Model:  nfb     b
Avg(logl(X)):   -275.030        -273.124
logl(Avg(X)):   -252.172        -251.069
DBar:   550.060 546.248
Dhat:   504.343 502.138
pD:     45.717  44.110
DIC:    595.777 590.358
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use process substitution to just get the 2nd column from file2 and give that as 2nd parameter to `paste` command like this:

```
$ paste -d $'\t' file1 <(awk '{print $2}' file2)
Model:  nfb b
Avg(logl(X)):   -275.030    -273.124
logl(Avg(X)):   -252.172    -251.069
DBar:   550.060 546.248
Dhat:   504.343 502.138
pD: 45.717  44.110
DIC:    595.777 590.358
$
```

Or you can just `join` command specifying the column on which you want to join(-1 1 -2 1=>implies 1st column in file1 and 1st column in file2)

```
$ join -1 1 -2 1 file1 file2
Model: nfb b
Avg(logl(X)): -275.030 -273.124
logl(Avg(X)): -252.172 -251.069
DBar: 550.060 546.248
Dhat: 504.343 502.138
pD: 45.717 44.110
DIC: 595.777 590.358
$
```

Comment: note that `-1 1 -2 1` can be abbreviated as `-j 1` or omitted since first key is by default the join field.

Answer (score 1):

there is tool for this `join`

```
$ join file1 file2

Model: nfb b
Avg(logl(X)): -275.030 -273.124
logl(Avg(X)): -252.172 -251.069
DBar: 550.060 546.248
Dhat: 504.343 502.138
pD: 45.717 44.110
DIC: 595.777 590.358
```

nothing else is required.

For preserving tabs

```
$ join -t $'\t' -j 2 file1 file2

Model:          nfb             b
Avg(logl(X)):           -275.030                -273.124
logl(Avg(X)):           -252.172                -251.069
DBar:           550.060         546.248
Dhat:           504.343         502.138
pD:             45.717          44.110
DIC:            595.777         590.358
```

Note about sort requirements:  In general, to find all matching records (many to many) the files need to be sorted.  However, as in this case, if you're matching keys in order (1-1 matching) the files don't need to be sorted.